# Creating a template Project management plan - Which tool?

Tags: project-management

I'm tasked with creating a PM plan template which can be reused on different corporate sites. That means that I will have a standard set of tasks which need to be listed. For each task, I need to be able to specify the predecessor, successor, duration and the resource. The point being that the local site PM can have an overview of the Project plan blueprint and can "easily" adapt it to the local situation.

I was trying to create this PM template in MS Project (version 2208) but I am unable to create a clear GANTT presentation using only the predecessor, successor, duration and the resource columns. As soon as I enter a duration, MS Project specifies a date. Finish to start dependencies are not respected in the GANTT presentation. I have tried a few suggested approaches from Stack Exchange like [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14676/ms-project-duration-without-a-start-and-finish-date?newreg=85ce00d520e74f5fbe2745fb0a089374) or [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/16803/creating-a-template-in-ms-project), but they seem to be of too little value for expected result.

Is there any free resource (I cannot possibly ask for a payed software for a one-time task) more suited to the above requisites?